# Does the BitTorrent Multitracker extension cause split swarms?

Tags: bittorrent, torrent

The [Wikipedia page of BitTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_tracker) says regarding Multitracker torrents, "One disadvantage to this is that it becomes possible to have multiple unconnected swarms for a single torrent where some users can connect to one specific tracker while being unable to connect to another. This can create a disjoint set which can impede the efficiency of a torrent to transfer the files it describes."

Can someone please give me an example of this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information on the wikipedia page is old and no longer relevant.

Split swarms was only a problem between the introduction of:
Multi-trackers extension:[BEP12](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0012.html) around 2004
and the introduction of:
PeerEXchange(PEX):[BEP11](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0011.html) and the DHT distributed tracker:[BEP5](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) around 2005.

These three extensions working together creates a single unified swarm.